# Lifetime of Ninject injected service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I want to know what is the lifetime of service injected by Ninject? And how to specify injected service live only of the duration http-request?

Comment: Please clarify more your question

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ninject object scope documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) objects are created by default with a '**transient scope**' and are only disposed when the Dispose() method is called on the object manually.

> Lifetime is not managed by the Kernel (the Scope object is null) and will never be Disposed

You can make it so objects only last the lifetime of the request by calling the '**InRequestScope()**' method when you create the binding:

```
kernel.Bind<X>().To<Y>().InRequestScope();
```